# SAP HANA - Error when trying to import data via Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, hana

I am trying to import a TXT file from my shared drive into a table in SAP HANA via Eclipse, but it seems I have a configuration issue somewhere.  The error I am receiving is this:

> **SAP DBTech JDBC: [2]: general error: Error: feature 'ImportExport.Import' is disabled. (See M_CUSTOMIZABLE_FUNCTIONALITIES)**

I googled the error but am not seeing any information on how to solve.  Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using a HANA2 SP03 **tenant** database.
For those certain features are not enabled by default. Instead, the admin user of the **SystemDB** needs to enable this feature for the specific tenant DB.